# How to store data on a temp table using Stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a Stored Procedure based on the Scalar function below to show that for each year and for each product there are how many customers? and if a product has no customers
then it should be in the result with Zero for the number of customers, so it should show all the products. and then I want to insert it to a temp table. This is what I've tried so far but for some points in SP I don't know what I have to do to get to my result. I guess it stuck in a loop :(
Any idea ??

THE SCALAR :

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumOfCustomers
(
    @year INT,
    @productId INT,
    @typeOfCustomer NVARCHAR
)
RETURNS TABLE AS 
RETURN
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Sales.Customer.CustomerID) AS number 

FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD 
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
        INNER JOIN Sales.Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID

WHERE
    SOD.ProductID = @productID 
    AND YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) = @year
    AND Sales.Customer.CustomerType = @typeOfCustomer
)
GO
```

THE STORED PROCEDURE :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYsp AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @year INT, @count INT
    DECLARE yearCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
    --ORDER BY YEAR DESC
    OPEN yearCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM  yearCursor INTO @year
    --** Starting the loop in curser and filling the data
    SET @count = 1
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

            DECLARE @prodID INT
            DECLARE @NumOfCustomers INT
            DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT P.ProductID FROM Production.Product P
            OPEN prodCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM  prodCursor INTO @prodID
            SET @count = 1
            WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN   
                SELECT @NumOfCustomers = NUM.number FROM NumOfCustomers(@year, @prodID, 's') NUM
                INSERT #temp (Year,ProductID,NumOfCustomers) VALUES (@year,@prodID,@NumOfCustomers)

                SET @count = @count+1
                FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor INTO @prodID
            END
            CLOSE prodCursor
            DEALLOCATE prodCursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM yearCursor INTO @year
    END
    CLOSE yearCursor
    DEALLOCATE yearCursor
END
GO
```

And then I want to execute it and get data from that temp table:

```
EXEC MYsp
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select statement inside procedure:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE MYsp AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @year INT, @count INT
        DECLARE yearCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
        --ORDER BY YEAR DESC
        OPEN yearCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM  yearCursor INTO @year
        --** Starting the loop in curser and filling the data
        SET @count = 1
        WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN

                DECLARE @prodID INT
                DECLARE @NumOfCustomers INT
                DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR FOR
                SELECT P.ProductID FROM Production.Product P
                OPEN prodCursor
                FETCH NEXT FROM  prodCursor INTO @prodID
                SET @count = 1
                WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
                BEGIN   
                    SELECT @NumOfCustomers = NUM.number FROM NumOfCustomers(@year, @prodID, 's') NUM
                    INSERT #temp (Year,ProductID,NumOfCustomers) VALUES (@year,@prodID,@NumOfCustomers)

                    SET @count = @count+1
                    FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor INTO @prodID
                END
                CLOSE prodCursor
                DEALLOCATE prodCursor

            FETCH NEXT FROM yearCursor INTO @year
        END
        CLOSE yearCursor
        DEALLOCATE yearCursor
    Select *
     from #temp
    END

GO
```

now execute procedure:

```
EXEC MYsp
```

Comment: Aziz It doesn't insert anything in the temp table... !
The error is: 
Procedure MYsp has no parameters and arguments were supplied.